# can't sync the current branch does not track a remote branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

I wanted to story my project on a git repository in case anything goes wrong on the old computer I'm working on. being the smart person I am I copied the wrong url when I went to publish and now I cant sync with visual studio. (currently using 2019)

I went and changed it to the correct url in the repository settings but it still says the above error and the sync/pull/push is grey/ unclickable.

I did quite a bit of googling but found nothing helpful. one thing I found was this:

[Visual studio/GIT : No tracked remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547932/visual-studio-git-no-tracked-remote-branch)

which talks about how to avoid getting here, but I just want to be able to sync with git now that I am here.

I've tried copying the project to a new folder and then deleting the .config .ignore and .attribue files as well and that didn't work.

here is what my team explorer currently looks like

[image: team explorer]

how do I make it so I can sync this project with git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for me was installing a git bash prompt then navigating to project root directory. then typing:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

you can install git from here https://git-scm.com/download/win