# The current branch does not track a remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

I must stress my usage of GIT (via VS2019 Team Explorer) has so far been fairly basic: 2 users, often working in sequence on the `Master` branch. Very happy to be suggested some reading for a deeper introduction to the concepts of GIT.

We wanted to start using GIT through a more *business-like* workflow. The idea is to keep the `Master` for core updates/upgrades, and to fork new branches based on past commits when publishing mini hot fixes: we pick the commit of the last publish, and create a new branch based on this commit; let's we call it `HotFix`. We do our fix, commit/publish/`push`, and then `merge` with the `Master`.

So we just started: Yesterday Mike created the `HotFix` branch, fixed a bug, committed, published the update, and `push`ed the commit to the remote. No merging with the Master was done yet. Today, Bob started Visual Studio, selected the `HotFix` branch, **did not pull**, and started to work on a second bug. Now he tries to `push`, but GIT is not happy and says:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before pushing again.

We understand this is because since he did not pull before starting to work, he is 1 commit behind Mike's/the Remote's version of the same branch. When this happens on the `Master`, we typically `pull` and merge/resolve any conflicts, and then `push` the work. But here, we cannot `pull`. There also is a message that says:

> The current branch does not track a remote branch.

We are a bit confused, because VS documentation says you need to push the branch so that it tracks the remote, but we cannot `push` because we are 1 commit behind the remote and should `pull` first, which requires `push`ing.. is this a catch 22 situation?

I read [here](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/track-remote-upstream-branch/) that `$ git branch -u origin/dev` will make "a tracking relationship for your current HEAD branch". I also feel that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547932/visual-studio-git-no-tracked-remote-branch) describe a similar scenario to ours; however the UX flow described in the most popular answer differs from what we have, I guess because we already have a remote repository, only the specific branch is problematic.

We understand the concepts of GIT and incremental versioning, but we know so little about its subtleties that I am scared of doing something irreversible. Could anyone confirm we are on the right track?

Comment: I don't use VSCode and am not sure if it requires any special handholding, but in raw Git you'd just run `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/HotFix HotFix` and now you have an upstream set and all is fine.

Comment: Apart from this, I *very strongly* recommend that you avoid **any** uppercase letters in **any** branch names when using any Windows system with Git. They will cause you misery later if someone uses a lowercase version, because Git itself thinks that these names are case-sensitive (`Master` and `master` are two entirely different branches) and *sometimes that's true* but *sometimes it's not because Windows*.

Comment: The remote tracking branch is not a necessity. When `git pull` does not work as expected, try `git pull origin dev` or `git pull origin -r dev`. In your case, the latter is better. Similarly, when `git push` does not work, try `git push origin HEAD:dev`. `git pull` and `git push` is a bit like `cp` or `scp`. If you don't specify the source and the target, the command has to find them somewhere else. If they exist nowhere, the command of course cannot work.

Comment: @torek I read that `git branch -u origin/dev` was the short version for `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev`, so went ahead and it worked. Thanks for your help, and the casing advise is also duly noted.

Comment: The `-u` option *was* an alias for `--set-upstream`, which had a syntax that caused people to use it "backwards" as it were. So I always write out the `--set-upstream-to` version, in case someone has an old version of Git. (The old `--set-upstream` is finally gone and `-u` means the corrected one now, but some people are still using Git 1.7 or 1.8!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into the Branches panel of the Team Explorer, right click on your repository and choose "Open Command Prompt", then type:

> git branch -u origin/HotFix

This will make the current local branch to track `origin/HotFix`.

Alternatively,

> git branch -u origin/HotFix LocalName

Will make the `LocalName` branch to track `origin/HotFix`. Usually, it is recommended to have `LocalName` being the same name as the upstream branch it tracks ([upstream refers to the branch on the server](https://devconnected.com/how-to-set-upstream-branch-on-git/)). As suggested in the comments, in the OP case this means `git branch -u origin/HotFix HotFix`.

Under the hood, tracking will result in Git updating locally a clone of the upstream branch. Then Git can compare the local branch with this local copy of the server branch.

It is then possible to Pull the commits of the upstream branch. If you have already committed on the branch, whilst some commits were pushed to the server by others, a merging operation is required before being able to push your own commits.

Some interesting reading: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches